# Elixir: Allow clients to run some predefined code which evaluates

Tags: elixir, phoenix-framework, dsl

I want my clients to be able to write something like `something <%= temp(@conn) %> something` where the `temp/1` function out of a specified module would be called and the output inserted whenever I display that. The set of functions would be very limited and predefined in this case because I don't want them to kill something.

How would I go about this?

To make it clear: I have sensors which have names. The client can edit these names to display whatever they want in the format they want when they go to a dashboard.

Comment: Do you really have the need for a super dynamic DSL like EEX? I'm not aware that you can scope down EEX compilations. "very limited and predefined" --> Maybe a simple old string replace will do?

Answer (score 2):

If string replacement doesn't get you there and you need a *safe* way to let users write templates that get parsed and rendered on your server, then:

This could be a good fit for a templating engine like [liquid](https://shopify.github.io/liquid/) (a ruby library). There is an Elixir implementation called [liquid-elixir](https://github.com/bettyblocks/liquid-elixir), I've never worked with it but I have some experience with the Ruby library.

Liquid provides you with a *simple/restricted* templating language where you can add tags, filters and provide custom local variables.

For example, if you assign a variable called `temp` that holds the current temperature, the user can use that in a template:

```
The temperature is {{ temp | round: 2 }}.

{% if temp <= 0 %}
  It's freezing!
{% endif %}
```

According to the readme of `liquid-elixir`, to render this on the server (lets assume the above is in the `user_template` variable):

```
temperature = MyApp.Sensor.current_temperature()
template = Liquid.Template.parse(user_template)
{:ok, rendered, _} = Liquid.Template.render(template, %{"temp" => temperature})
```

And now you have some HTML in `rendered` that you can use/display.

Again, I have no experience with the Elixir version, I don't know if it is feature complete or even works at all.

Answer (score 0):

Liquid-Elixir suggested by zwippie sounds like overkill (as he said). So I'm going to post my solution for anyone who might be having a similar issue. It's a lot less code than I originally expected and only a little less flexible.

```
defmodule AppWeb.DSLHelper do
  @moduledoc false

  @pattern ~r/{{\s?([a-zA-Z_]*)\s?}}/

  def extract(name, message) do
    Regex.replace(@pattern, name, fn(_all, capture) -> replace(capture, message) end)
  end


  defp replace(what, message), do: "#{Map.get(message, what)}"
end
```

People can now write `something {{temp}}°C` and get `something 20.05°C`